# Qual a função desse trecho de código? Estrutura de dados (Lista)

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Preciso entender o que cada comando desse é capaz de de fazer, pois está sem comentários.

```
struct Node{
    int num;
    struct Node *prox;
};

typedef struct Node node;

int tam;

int vazia(node *LISTA)
{
    if(LISTA->prox == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

node *aloca()
{
    node *novo=(node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(!novo){
        printf("Sem memoria disponivel!\n");
        exit(1);
    }else{
        printf("Novo elemento: ");
        scanf("%d", &novo->num);
        return novo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Não tem uma dúvida mais específica? Tem que explicar linha por linha? Este código não é uma boa referência, ele poderia ser bem melhor escrito.

Comment: Apenas o que cada bloco é capaz de fazer, não precisa ser a linha por linha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Começando pelo inicio:

- A estrutura:

  ```
  struct Node{
      int num;
      struct Node *prox;
  };
  ```

  Isto cria a estrutura para cada nó da lista, que irá ter um numero e o 
  ponteiro para o próximo nó. Algo que em memoria será representado como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- O `typedef`:

  ```
  typedef struct Node node;
  ```

  Faz com que seja possível de utilizar o nome `node` referindo-se à 
  estrutura `struct Node` tornando fácil a sua utilização no código.
- Função `vazia`:

  ```
  int vazia(node *LISTA)
  {
      if(LISTA->prox == NULL)
          return 1;
      else
          return 0;
  }
  ```

  Testa apenas se o nó recebido como parâmetro representa uma lista vazia. Este teste é feito verificando se o elemento seguinte ao recebido é nulo (`NULL`) e retorna `1` caso seja. Note que esta implementação apenas irá funcionar numa lista com sentinela. Numa lista convencional o teste de lista vazia é feito testando apenas se o primeiro nó é nulo.
- Função `aloca`:

  ```
  node *aloca()
  {
      node *novo=(node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
      if(!novo){
          printf("Sem memoria disponivel!\n");
          exit(1);
      }else{
          printf("Novo elemento: ");
          scanf("%d", &novo->num);
         return novo;
     }
  }
  ```

  Esta função tenta alocar espaço para um novo nó utilizando a função [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) que devolve um ponteiro valido se teve sucesso ou `NULL` caso contrario. Este é o motivo do `if (!novo)` que verifica se não foi possível alocar e nesse caso dá uma mensagem e termina. Se teve sucesso lê o numero a colocar no nó com `scanf` e devolve esse nó com `return`.

**Melhorando**

Toda essa lógica podia ser melhorada e simplificada, ora veja um exemplo:

```
typedef  struct Node{
    int num;
    struct Node *prox;
} node; //typedef ao mesmo tempo que declara a estrutura

int tam;

int vazia(node *LISTA)
{
    //assim contempla também o primeiro nó em si estar vazio
    return LISTA == NULL || LISTA->prox == NULL;
}
```

O `aloca` também pode e deve ser melhorado separando a lógica da lista com a introdução dos dados, mas apenas com o código que está na pergunta não é possível de reformular.

Comment: Poxa, valeu mesmo!! ficou bem mais claro ;D

Comment: @ElderSon Ainda bem. Fico contente por ter ajudado :)